# Swift MapView Stuck Around User's Current Location

Tags: swift, mkmapview

Currently, my code drops a pin on the user's current location. There is one small problem when I try to move the map around, because the view will shift back and be centered around that current location pin. I want the user be able to navigate the map and move it around, and if the user switches view controllers (goes to another tab) and comes back, the map will be centered around the user location pin. I have been trying to modify this code to do this, but I have not had any luck where to start.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
let newPin = MKPointAnnotation()

class MapVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {



@IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!

 let locationManager =  CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // User's location

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    } else {
    // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()


    // add gesture recognizer
    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MapVC.mapLongPress(_:))) // colon needs to pass through info
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.5 // in seconds
    //add gesture recognition
    map.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
}

// func called when gesture recognizer detects a long press

func mapLongPress(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

    print("A long press has been detected.")

    let touchedAt = recognizer.location(in: self.map) // adds the location on the view it was pressed
    let touchedAtCoordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D = map.convert(touchedAt, toCoordinateFrom: self.map) // will get coordinates

    let newPin = MKPointAnnotation()
    newPin.coordinate = touchedAtCoordinate
    map.addAnnotation(newPin)


}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {


    map.removeAnnotation(newPin)

    let location = locations.last! as CLLocation

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

    //set region on the map
    map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    newPin.coordinate = location.coordinate
    map.addAnnotation(newPin)





}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has several problems:

You declare a variable `newPin` at global scope and in `mapLongPress(...)` you declare a new variable `let newPin = ...` locally so the global `newPin` isn't used.

In `didUpdateLocations()` you first remove the (global) `newPin` annotation (why??) and set it again at the end of the function. Because the global `newPin` was never set to anything useful this will never get the desired result.

Furthermore, in `didUpdateLocations()` you set the map's region and center point to the current location. This is done on every location update, giving weird results when trying to pan the map.

To set center and region when the view appears, try something like that:

```
class MapVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    let locationManager =  CLLocationManager()

    // class variable for the current location
    var lastLocation: CLLocation?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // ...
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if self.lastLocation != nil {
            // set center and region to current location
            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.lastLocation.coordinate.latitude, longitude: self.lastLocation.coordinate.longitude)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))

            //set region on the map
            map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        self.lastLocation = locations.last
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah I see the local variable newPin from mapLongPress is redundant. As for the didUpdateLocations(), I was not aware that if was constantly updating. How can I get it to update just when the view controller is opened, so the user can be able to pan the map?

Comment: You can save the last retrieved location in a class variable and set region and center point in `ViewDidAppear`

Comment: This may sound naive but please bear with me. How can I set the class variable so that I can save location (or region/center point) outside the function didUpdateLocations()? I would only know how to do this using a global variable.

Comment: Ok, I think I have a better understanding of what is going on. First I understand what didUpdateLocations() does (I wouldn't want it to be updated everytime) and viewDidAppear makes sense (because I am only interested in it showing at the onset). However, could you explain what the code "self.lastLocation = locations.last! as CLLocation" does? Second, am I able to access a variable outside a function by prefacing the variable with "self."?

Comment: `didUpdateLocations` gets called whenever a new location is detected. With `self.lastLocation = locations.last` you set the variable `lastLocation` to the current location. This variable can be accessed in every function of your class `MapVC`. But this is going far beyond the question, this is swift basics.

Comment: I see, thanks for helping me understand more about this delegate method.